# jQuery validation of two fields len().

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys I am using jQuery Validation plugin to validate the Input Text fields...

like this:

```
$("#formSettings").validate({

        rules: {
            sta: {
                required: true,

            },
            crs: {
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    },
    messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please Provide Your Email Address",
                email: "Provide Valid Email Address"
            },
    });
```

The issue: I need to match one textfield value with the other, each textfield have comma separated values and they should match before continuing, any idea how can I do that

like if textfield 1 is: 1,2,3,4,5,6 then textfield2 should match.

Comment: Do you want to validate the length or the content?

Comment: I think he needs both

Comment: length, not the content, if the length is 6, the other field validating should also be count to 6

Comment: So then you are only concerned about matching length matching so use: yourTextFieldString.length

Comment: Yes match the length of the values inside the text which are comma separated

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selector').val().length
```

Above the basic jQuery version of .length After that you could do an if statement. Here is a brief untested test you try:

```
<input type="text" value="1,2,3,4,5" id="thing1">
<input type="text" value="1,2,3,4" id="thing2">
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">


$('#submit').click(function(event){

    var thing1 = $('#thing1').val().length;
    var thing2 = $('#thing2').val().length;

    if (thing1 == thing2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Contents must have same length");
        return false;
    }

});
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8XQB3/

Comment: Thanks, Can i add this in the jquery validation function

Comment: trying to make it like this to add a function to validator, am i correct or not, please correct me if wrong: `$.validator.addMethod("sametosame", 
function(element) {
    var thing1 = $(element).val().length;
    var thing2 = $(element).val().length; 
    if (thing1 == thing2) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    } 
},'Contents must have same length');`

Comment: Check my updated code.  I have by passed your jQuery validation stuff to give you a nice simple basic example.